# Executing code when webfonts asynchronously load and other scripts at the bottom

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, typekit, webfont-loader

I'm using Typekit's code snippet for asynchronous loading, located in the `<head>`, the rest of my JavaScript is located at the bottom of the `<body>`. This is the configuration part of Typekit's script:

```
var config = {
  kitId: 'tca8gie',
  scriptTimeout: 3000,
  active: function() {

    $heroUnit = $(".hero-unit");
    if ($heroUnit.length)
      $heroUnit.find("h1, .lead").slabText({
        viewportBreakpoint: 600
      });

  }
};
```

I added the `active` callback where I'm activating [slabText](http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/slabText/) when the webfonts load. In 99% of the times this works, but in that 1% of the times jQuery that's at the bottom of my page doesn't get loaded yet, so this slabText code results in a `Can't find variable: jQuery` error and doesn't work.

How do I execute this code exactly when webfonts, jQuery and slabText load?

Comment: So you have placed the jQuery inclusion code at the `<body>` bottom?

Comment: I bet you are using google's CDN for your jquery.js, (common issue) you can just download jquery.min.js and paste slabText.js to the end of it.  Then trigger your starter function with an onload event

Comment: Yes, my jQuery is at the bottom, along with the other scripts, because they'll all be concatenated in the production. So the problem is that the webfonts are downloading asynchronously and the scripts on the bottom synchonously (that's why I put them at the bottom). I don't know how to defer executing that code until jQuery and slabText load, because for that functionality (deferreds) i need jQuery :P

Comment: (I'm not using CDN for jQuery.)